# Running shell methods via libmongoc?

Tags: mongodb, libmongoc

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to run [shell methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/) via libmongoc. I can run [database commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) by using the method [mongoc_client_command](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/mongoc_client_command.html). So for example, I can run `listDatabases` through mongoc_client_command, but I cannot run `db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )`.

1. Is it possible to run shell methods via the libmongoc library?
2. If not, is there and alternative api to run shell commands on Mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongo` shell commands are just convenience wrappers for the underlying [database command API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/).

If you invoke most shell helpers without parentheses you can see what commands are being run. For example, `db.adminCommand` runs a command against the `admin` database:

```
> db.adminCommand
function (obj, extra) {
    if (this._name == "admin")
        return this.runCommand(obj, extra);
    return this.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand(obj, extra);
}
```

Through the `libmongoc` interface you would pass `admin` as the `db_name` parameter to run a command with an equivalent outcome to `db.adminCommand()`.